# Opening Raster stored in Esri Geodatabase using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2, esri-geodatabase

Is there a way to open a raster that is stored in ESRI V10.0 Geodatabase in QGIS V2.4?

I can open the vector layer, but there does not seems to be a way to open a raster.

Comment: There are many geodatabase formats.  Are you referring to a File Geodatabase?  Please update the question to either specify FGDB or the underlying RDBMS.

Answer (score 7):

QGIS doesn't support ESRI Geodatabase raster.
The only solution is to open the database in ArcGIS an export the raster GeoTiff.

- Right click in arcCatalog, Export/Raster to different Format...
- Then choose a folder and fileaname to write to
- if the extension is .tif, it will be readable in QGIS

Answer (score 3):

If it's a file/personal based geodatabase - you can't access raster (yet). One of the developers for the http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html has mentioned working on that ability if funding was available.

As far as SDE goes - I'm unsure.