# Converting ESRI Raster Dataset to QGIS compatible Dataset?

Tags: qgis, raster, file-geodatabase

I am trying to convert an ESRI .gdb "File Geodatabase Raster Dataset" (Format: FGDBR) to an QGIS compatible File with or without using ArcMap.

Comment: Related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110533/open-raster-stored-in-esri-v10-0-geodatabase-in-qgis-v2-4

Comment: Try this https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to export the image from file geodatabase into a raster file, as I don't believe QGIS can open the file geodatabase raster directly.

1. In ArcMap Catalog window (or in ArcCatalog itself) browse to your raster dataset in your file geodatabase
2. Right-click the raster dataset, and select Export > Raster to different format
3. Select a path to save the raster file to, and choose a raster format that can be opened in QGIS.
4. Open QGIS and add the new raster file

---

See [GDAL Raster Formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) for a list of raster types that should be able to be opened in QGIS.  `TIF`, `PNG`, `JPG` are possibly the more common types.

Not all the raster formats in that link are exportable from ArcGIS.  These are the formats exportable using the Raster to Different Format tool in ArcMap:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked well but where can I see the attribute table with the data in QGIS? The attribute table seems to be missing in QGIS. Is there another way to look at the data?

Comment: @LaTradision That is a new question - please ask it separately to this one. See [ask].

Comment: Raster attribute tables are not yet supported by qgis http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/32803/2856